# Descriptive Statistics for Binary Variables

Tags: stata

I am attempting to create a descriptive table that provides me with the count of each specific variable mentioned. When I use the following code it just gives me the total number of observations. How do I get the total count of award_winner when it is equal to one only? award_winner is a binary variable for 1 = received the award and 0 = did not receive the award. registered is the total number of businesses.

`asdoc summ registered i.award_winner`

Comment: The count of values that are 1 in a (0, 1) variable is precisely the _sum_ of that variable.  I've no idea how that plays with `asdoc` (from SSC, as you are asked to explain) but it may help

Comment: When i use the summ command it just gives me the total number of observations it does not give the total count for 0 or for 1.

Comment: `summarize` does calculate the sum, but does not display it. See the `help` for `summarize` which explains that the sum is left in `r(sum)` after the command runs, so it can be accessed that way.

Comment: @Attaullah Shah, the author of `asdoc`,  is a member here, but you're much more likely to get an answer on `asdoc` if you ask on Statalist.

Comment: You should accept more answers to boost your reputation and reward posters.